# date filtering in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
set @vSqlFilters = '(ABRA.START_DATE !> ' + cast(@dEndDate as varchar(26)) + ' or ABRA.END_DATE !< ' + cast(@dStartDate as varchar(26)) + ')';
```

I want my parameters @dStartDate and @dEndDate to keep the quotes around them.  Currently, they're typed in manually by the end user with the quotes around them.  Right now, I just get

`(ABRA.START_DATE !> 2013-05-01 or ABRA.END_DATE !< 2011-04-05)` in my query instead of

```
(ABRA.START_DATE !> '2013-05-01' or ABRA.END_DATE !< '2011-04-05').
```

Since this is thrown into a dynamic SQL query, I need my @dEndDate and @dStartDate to be cast as strings.  Also I want it to treat my dStartDate and dEndDate as dates not integers.  I just don't see how I can get SQL to compare my dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put doubled-up single quotes anywhere within the statement you want a single quote to appear:

```
set @vSqlFilters = '(ABRA.START_DATE !> ''' + cast(@dEndDate as varchar(26))
+ ''' or ABRA.END_DATE !< ''' + cast(@dStartDate as varchar(26)) + ''')';
```

However, there is no need to do this. With `sp_executesql` you can just use parameters:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.ABRA ABRA WHERE ABRA.START_DATE <= @dEndDate'
+ ' AND ABRA.END_DATE >= @dStartDate';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dStartDate datetime, @dEndDate datetime',
@dStartDate, @dEndDate;
```

This is, in my mind, better practice. It also may offer better performance through execution plan reuse (or it may not).

I would also like to recommend that you NOT use inequality operators `!`, `!<`, and `!>`. They make it hard for others to read and comprehend your code. use `<>`, `>=`, and `<=`.

Last, are you sure you wanted `OR` in your filter? I may be missing something.

Comment: Yep, I wanted OR in my filter.  I know it looks weird and I can't go into detail without spilling company details.  You'll just have to bear with me.

Comment: Oh, and about the `OR`, I find that very strange. Assuming that `END_DATE` is always greater than `START_DATE`, `OR` here is going to return **every row in the entire table**! I'm baffled. :)